# "Call to undefined function" when calling a function in custom composer package

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

PHP experts! I'm trying to make my code more modular according to the ways of PHP (using 7.0) and this is my first experiment creating my own combination of namespace + composer package + git repository.

My package directory:

```
packagedir
|__src
|   |__myfunc.php
|__composer.json
```

myfunc.php:

```
namespace MyNS\MySubNS;
function myfunc() { return 1; }
```

packagedir/composer.json:

```
{
  "name": "myns/mysubns",
  ...
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "MyNS\\MySubNS\\": "src" }
  }
}
```

All checked into repository `packagedir/.git.`

My project directory after composer install:

```
public_html
|__vendor
|   |__composer
|   |   |__ [all the usual autoload_* stuff, etc.]
|   |__myns
|   |   |__mysubns 
|   |       |__src
|   |       |   |__myfunc.php
|   |       |__composer.json
|   |__autoload.php
|__composer.json
|__composer.lock
|__index.php
```

public_html/composer.json:

```
{
  "require": {
    "myns/mysubns": "dev-master"
  },
  "repositories": [
    { "type": "git",
      "url": "file:///path/to/packagedir/.git" }
  ]
}
```

index.php:

```
ini_set('display_errors','1');
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
echo \MyNS\MySubNS\myfunc();
```

It looks like composer installed the package in `vendor`, and `autoload_ps4.php` includes:

```
return array(
    'MyNS\\MySubNS\\' => array($vendorDir . '/myns/mysubns/src'),
);
```

But I get:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function MyNS\MySubNS\myfunc() in /var/www/public_html/index.php on line 3
( ! ) Error: Call to undefined function MyNS\MySubNS\myfunc() in /var/www/public_html/index.php on line 3
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong (aside from the advice that .git repositories are not recommended as a place to get packages)?

Comment: Just a tip, as the question is already answered; look at other projects how they do it. Example of the Laravel framework `composer.json` (note the helpers): https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/composer.json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP does not autoload functions. Use the [`files` autoloader](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files), eg:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": ["src/MyLibrary/functions.php"]
    }
}
```

or enclose them in a class and autoload that, eg:

```
namespace foo;
class Helper {
    public static function foo() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: This was very helpful. I was wondering why my custom package was not working and it was because it uses a file. Your first suggestion of using the "files" autoloader was spot on. Thank you @Sammitch